# Communication from cross-domain iframe to parent window

Tags: html, angular, iframe, cross-domain

i have my parent component in which i'm displaying iframe of diffrent domain. it opens a iframe, In that i need to capture a button click event inside the iframe and need to pass that event to parent component

i have tried using window.postMessage and window.addEventListener, but couldn't make out

Comment: postMessage and eventlisteners are indeed the way forward for cross-origin events. Where is the code where you are attempting to use them? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: @JoshuaT i'm calling the window.addEventListener in my parent component and window.postMessage in iframe.

Comment: Ok, but you need to post your actual code that you have tried, here, in your question (you can edit your question to add it). How are we supposed to diagnose what is wrong with your code if we can't see it? If you are looking for a starting spot, the [examples on MDN are excellent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Example).

Answer (score 0):

It is a cross access control issue. 
If you have access to the server of iframe source, add this code to the htaccess file:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Comment: postMessage does not require that parent and child share origin, or that CORs  headers are set correctly. That's kind of the the whole point of postMessage. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage): "Any window may access this method on any other window, at any time, regardless of the location of the document in the window, to send it a message."

Comment: he wanted to add an event listener to the button inside the iframe.

Comment: Yes, but that still doesn't change the fact that no special headers are needed to postMessage from a child iframe to a parent. If he controls the iframe,  he can add an event listener within the iframe to the button click and relay it via postMessage to the parent, which can listen for it via another event listener, regardless of origin, without any special headers. If you find documentation to the contrary, please share, but I have definitely used this approach before without requiring special headers sent. Don't confuse sending events with sending actual network requests (AJAX).